# How to write the heading at the top of of file generated by a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, file-io, awk

I have a shell script that writes some data in a file. I want to add a heading `"Instance Details"` which should be centre aligned before printing the actual data in the file.

I have tried this code:

```
out="Instances_$today_date"

awk -F'\t' -v of="$out" '

    # (input and other code omitted...)

    BEGIN { # Set the printf() format string for the header and the data lines.
    fmt = "%-12s %-33s %-15s %s\n"
    # Print the header
    printf("Instance Details") > of
      printf(fmt, "Instance id", "Name", "Owner", "Cost.centre") > of

}'
```

**But the output I am getting after executing this code:**

```
Instance DetailsInstance id  Name                              Owner           Cost.centre
```

**Expected Output:**

```
                              Instance Details


Instance id  Name                              Owner           Cost.centre
```

Any lead is highly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you expect "Instance Details" to come out centered?

Comment: This is  actually the heading in the file.

Comment: Please go ahead. It's a heading and... what exactly should make it centered? Can you point out which line in the code is responsible for that?

Comment: The issue is resolved Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
awk -F'\t' -v of="$out" '

  # (input and other code omitted...)

  BEGIN { # Set the printf() format string for the header and the data lines.
     # Print the header
    headerText="Instance Details"
    headerMaxLen=74
    padding=(length(headerText) - headerMaxLen) / 2
    printf("%" padding "s" "%s" "%" padding "s"  "\n\n\n", "", headerText, "") > of
    fmt="%-12s %-33s %-15s %s\n"
    printf(fmt, "Instance id", "Name", "Owner", "Cost.centre") >> of
  }'
```

- Passes in the name of the output file via variable `of`.
- Calculates the necessary padding on either side of `Instance Details` to make it appear centered on the output line (line length derived from the length of the final line of output).
- Outputs `Instance Details` with 3 newlines to create the desired empty lines.
- (Note that it doesn't matter whether the *2nd* `printf` statement uses `> of` or `>> of` - in either event the file is *appended* to.)

Comment: @mklenment0: actually I have already defined the `of`. Kindly see few more lines in my script

Comment: @MeghaSharma: OK, I've matched your updated code; seems to me the `pr()` function is incidental to the problem at hand, so I didn't include it. Note that in your code you keep _overwriting_ output file `of` by using `> of` instead of `>> of`; Try my code without any input to `awk` to see if it outputs the desired header to `of`.

Comment: @mklenment0: even without '>>` I am getting the desired output. Is that a good practice?

Comment: @MeghaSharma: I stand corrected: output redirection in `awk` works such that multiple uses of `>` targeting the same output file _append_ to the file, so in statements _other_ than the first that writes to a given file you can use `>` and `>>` interchangeably. The _first_ statement that writes to a given file matters, however: if it uses `>`, the existing output file is truncated first.

Comment: @MeghaSharma: You should provide feedback so as to help future readers of this page: if you feel my answer _solved_ your question, click on the large check mark; if you feel the answer was at least _helpful_, click on the large up arrow to up-vote it.

Comment: Sorry I cannt upvote as I don't have 15 reputations :(

Comment: @MeghaSharma: No worries - you already _accepted_ it - that's enough; thanks.